# Cucina: perlatura e mantecatura

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, etymology, cooking

Volevo chiedere se alcuno di voi sa, in cucina, che differenza c'è tra perlatura e mantecatura.

Ognuno di questi è probabilmente un termine italiano, culinario, che non trova paralleli in altre lingue (in quanto, probabilmente, specifico alla cucina italiana).

Ma, forse non è così. In tal caso, vorrei sapere anche di cose simili in altre culture e tradizioni e traduzioni, di queste parole, o di questi concetti, in altre lingue.

Ma, torniamo anche alla domanda originale. Che differenza c'è tra una perlatura e una mantecatura?

Comment: Ti riferisci alla perlatura di cui si parla per esempio qui? http://www.sandonatosnc.it/servizi.asp Se sì, è un procedimento dell'industria dei cereali e non vedo bene il nesso con la mantecatura o in genere con la cucina. O si usa anche per qualche altro concetto?